# How to install Ubuntu from an ISO on my Android to Linpus with CLI

Tags: ubuntu, usb, system-installation, live-usb, acer

I have bought a laptop with Linpus without GUI (as far as I know). I downloaded ubuntu on a ISO on my Android.

I have:

- Android phone with internet
- USB cable
- An 8gb pendrive that i just bought
- An Ubuntu ISO on mobile
- and this bloody laptop with with Linpus installed on it

So what can I do?

Comment: Welcome, If the android device is rooted you can use the [DriveDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.softwarebakery.drivedroid&hl=en) app.

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia, Linpus should definitely have a GUI, so I'll have to assume that the Linpus installation is somehow incomplete. Based on that, I'm not going to try guessing what Android-compatible file transfer tools might be available.

So:

- Go to a friend, workplace, library or some other location that allows you access to a fully-functional personal computer. Take the phone, the pendrive and the USB cable with you.
- Use whatever means available to transfer the ISO file to the computer.
- Follow the instructions in [Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) to write the ISO to the pendrive.

(Note that Ubuntu installation ISOs are prepared with `isohybrid`, so you can simply write the ISO to the pendrive like a generic hard disk image file, overwriting any existing contents of the pendrive.)

But if you find out a way to transfer the ISO file to the laptop, then you probably can use that for writing the ISO to the pendrive: you'll only need the `dd` command for that. Plug in the pendrive, run `dmesg`, look at the tail end of the output to identify the `/dev/sd*` device corresponding to the pendrive, and run a command like:

```
sudo dd if=ubuntu-iso-image.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=1024k
```

Now you should have an USB stick that can be used as Ubuntu installation media.